# jmeter dashboard report includes transaction controller children

Tags: controller, transactions, jmeter, dashboard

I'm using jmeter v5.0. I have put my HTTP requests inside of Transaction Controllers with "Generate parent Sample" checkbox checked as shown below.  When I run the test in GUI mode the aggregate report shows as expected with only the Transaction Controllers.

However, when I generate a report and then the charts and graphs from the command line, the aggregate report and all other charts/graphs include the controller and children.

```
jmeter -n -t ntwebMetisMaster.jmx -l 1.jtl
jmeter -g 1.jtl -o 1
```

Is there a setting in jmeter.properties I need to change?  I'm using defaults.

Thanks in advance for any help.

[Controller screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMr4o.png)
[GUI aggregate report screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFiCN.png)
[Dashboard Aggregate screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NT3J.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The setting you're looking for is [`jmeter.save.saveservice.subresults`](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config), you need to set it to `false`

However please avoid modifying *jmeter.properties* file otherwise you may run into the situation when it will be overwritten during upgrade to the next JMeter version. You can add the next line to *user.properties* file instead:

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.subresults=false
```

And next time you start JMeter it will be applied.

You can also pass the property via [`-J` command-line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override) like:

```
jmeter -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.subresults=false -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl -e -o report
```

More information: [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: I have just tried this for a JMeter script that has a controller that I stated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73723517/transaction-controller-does-not-report-correct-total-time but all the children still get populated in the dashboard is there anything I missing @dmitri

Comment: You can filter them out using `jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.series_filter` [JMeter Property](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization) during [dashboard generation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#report). Embedded resources and transaction controllers children can be removed using i.e.   `^[^-]*[^ -](-success|-failure)?$` pattern