# Transaction Controller does not report correct total time

Tags: jmeter

I have this setup in Jmeter but the summary report does not report the time it takes for the  while loop to finish, seems to just report the HTTP Request time only.

I have selected the option to "Include duration of timer and pre-post processors in generated sample" but the summary report does not seem to include the total time it takes for the while loop to complete.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flow Control Action sampler doesn't generate a SampleResult therefore it's not "visible" for the Transaction Controller

I can think of replacing it with i.e. [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) with the following code:

```
sleep(60000L)
```

also with regards to your Beanshell Sampler: [since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so it worth considering migrating, see [Beanshell vs. JSR223 vs. Java For JMeter: Complete Showdown](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-jmeter) article for more information.

Comment: That works perfectly thanks, do you have a link to where in the documentation it states that Flow Control Action samplers time does not should up in the sample result?

Comment: https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action `Rather than generate a sample, the test element either pauses or stops the selected target`